# FullCalendar Multiple businesshours per resource in Resource TimeLineView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, outsystems

I want to view multiple business hours in the ResourceTimeLine view, so I implemented multiple business hours for by resource. For example, Monday to Wednesday - 8H to 17H and Thursday to Friday - 15H to 23H for a resource, other resource with another business hour.

In Docs of Fullcalendar component (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours-per-resource) says its possible with an array:

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
      {
        daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
        startTime: '08:00', // 8am
        endTime: '18:00' // 6pm
      },
      {
        daysOfWeek: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
        startTime: '10:00', // 10am
        endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
      }
    ]
```

In Outsystems I define my Business Hours an array and It's ok, appears the correct information, but when I drag and drop an event to a resource it doesn't invoke the action to save the change.

[image]

If I implement a single business hour it already invoke the action and save the change information when I drag and drop an event to a resource. But I need multiple business hours. I don't find the source of this problem. Can you please help me?

My Json object about Outsystems component of the Full Calendar, :

```
"newResource":{
        "id":"8547",
        "title":"Adelino Silva",
        "parentId":"1",
        "businessHours":{
            "defs":{
                "0":    {"groupId":"_businessHours", "title":"", "url":"", "rendering":"inverse-background", "extendedProps":{}, "publicId":"", "ui":{"startEditable":null, "durationEditable":null, "constraints":[], "overlap":null, "allows":[], "backgroundColor":"", "borderColor":"", "textColor":"", "classNames":["fc-nonbusiness"]}, "defId":"0", "sourceId":"", "allDay":false, "hasEnd":true, "resourceIds":[], "resourceEditable":null, "recurringDef":{"typeId":0,"typeData":{"daysOfWeek":[1,2,3,4,5],"startTime":{"years":0,"months":0,"days":0,"milliseconds":28800000},"endTime":{"years":0, "months":0,"days":0, "milliseconds":45000000}, "startRecur":null,"endRecur":null}, "duration":{"years":0, "months":0, "days":0, "milliseconds":16200000}}},
                "1":{"groupId":"_businessHours", "title":"", "url":"", "rendering":"inverse-background", "extendedProps":{},"publicId":"","ui":{"startEditable":null,"durationEditable":null,"constraints":[],"overlap":null,"allows":[],"backgroundColor":"","borderColor":"","textColor":"","classNames":["fc-nonbusiness"]},"defId":"1","sourceId":"","allDay":false,"hasEnd":true,"resourceIds":[],"resourceEditable":null,"recurringDef":{"typeId":0,"typeData":{"daysOfWeek":[1,2,3,4,5],"startTime":{"years":0,"months":0,"days":0,"milliseconds":48600000},"endTime":{"years":0,"months":0,"days":0,"milliseconds":61200000},"startRecur":null,"endRecur":null},"duration":{"years":0,"months":0,"days":0,"milliseconds":12600000}}}
                },
            "instances":{}
        },
```

Next video example without business hours and with multiple business hours.

- Without Business Hours: [1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriiQoleUEDDXRm-c](http://1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriiQoleUEDDXRm-c)
- With Multiple Business Hours: [1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriemTG7IiuJd40VP](http://1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriemTG7IiuJd40VP)

Comment: We can't find the source of your problem if you don't show the code and event data you're using. Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mre] of your issue, and then update your post. (Note: please provide code as text, not screenshots). Thanks.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. My problem is when I define my calendar with multiple business hours not call the action to save the changes when I drag and drop an event to a resource with multiple business hours. I suspect is the structure of the business hours not accept the array structure but in Docs of Full Calendar says its possible. Next video example without business hours and with multiple business hours. 
Without Business Hours: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriiQoleUEDDXRm-c
With Multiple Business Hours: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlbeY8lpgVAeriemTG7IiuJd40VP

Comment: You must share a [mre] of your problem **here** in the question. Code in 3rd party storage is not accepted. This is explained in [ask] and in the [help/on-topic]. This is to ensure the question stays intact in future even if other services cease or links / content are changed or removed. The purpose of stackoverflow is to make questions and answers which are useful to future readers, not just you, so having it all available here in the question is a key requirement of that. Please edit your question, and show actual **code** as **text**. videos/pictures can be added for extra illustration only

Comment: Again please share a [mre] of the issue. We still can't see your fullCalendar Javascript code. That definition of the multiple businessHours looks wrong - there should not be a `defs` property. Where exactly did you get that from? Please show the source code, not some console output. If you're using some kind of automated code generation tool then it's going to be difficult for us to help you because we cannot see the code it generates - unless perhaps you can look in your browser's Developer Tools to see what actually appears on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is on CallbackEvent Structure, not accept the BusinessHours list by Resource.
The solution:
I created a Resource structure with single business hour for CallbackEvent Structure and it's work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQrk3.png)